# unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.1

Tags: playframework, sbt

Updated my play framework version to 2.2.1

```
C:\>where play
C:\apps\play-2.2.1\play
C:\apps\play-2.2.1\play.bat
```

On Doing a build I get following error as shown below.

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.1: not found
```

Comment: Can you show us your `build.properties`, `build.sbt` and/or `Build.scala` files?

Answer (score 5):

Add this:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at
  "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

to `project/plugins.sbt`, and make sure your top-level `build.sbt` has this line:

```
playScalaSettings
```

I don't know of any reason it would need to be more complicated than that, as in your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by entering the following entry in `Resolvers.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import scala.xml.XML

object Resolvers { 
/*
# Online play 2.2.0 repository 
#
*/
val onLinePlayRepo = "Online Play Repository" at
  "https://private-repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/play/"

val remResolvers = Seq(localMaven, 
                       localIvy,
                       localPlay, 
                       sonatypeReleases,
                       sonatypePublic,
                       typesafeSnapshots,
                       typesafeReleases,
                       mavenRepository,
                       mavenRepositoryOne,
                       onLinePlayRepo)
```

Also added in build.sbt the following entries.

```
import sbt._ 

resolvers  += "Online Play Repository" at
  "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/maven-releases/"
```

Comment: Where can I find this Resolvers.scala file? When using play command it finds the sbt dependency in wrong resolvers. I already added one in build.sbt but cant find Resolvers.scala. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, you should set https proxy as far as http proxy.

**HTTPS**

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=host -Dhttps.proxyPort=port
```

**HTTP**

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=port
```