# sbt does not resolve Typesafe repository

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy, typesafe

I have an odd problem with sbt and the Typesafe repository:

```
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.2.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.10/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.10/2.2.0/play-json_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.10/2.2.0/play-json_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.2.0: not found
```

I can manually download both .pom and .jar from http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.10/2.2.0/ so the server is definitely there.

Is this perhaps an sbt problem? Any clues why it would fail if it definitely has the right URL?

Comment: The repo.typesafe site is down,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is an unknown problem with the resolver

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865840/unresolved-dependency-com-typesafe-playplay-2-102-2-1), the problem can be solved by adding yet another resolver:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Simple Repository" at
  "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/maven-releases/"
```

Answer (score 2):

For people facing this issue in 2020 onwards, please replace http part with https in resolver url.

Ref: https://www.lightbend.com/blog/lightbend-to-require-https-on-repos-starting-august-5-2020